# MVVM в C#. Помогите разобраться

Tags: c#, mvvm

В общем, перелопатив кучу материала, я окончательно запутался. С `view` всё понятно, а вот `model` и `viewmodel` вызывают вопросы. Предположим, есть модель:

```
class PersonModel{
 public string Name {get; set;}
 public string LastName {get; set;}
}
```

ViewModel этой модели, как я понимаю, хранит ссылку на `PersonModel`, команды и общается с UI. Теперь **вопрос №1:** Кто выполняет CRUD операции? Модель сама себя хранит, этим занимается ViewModel или вообще какой-нибудь менеджер? Как архитектурно более правильно?

**Вопрос №2:** Как должна выглядеть `ViewModel` для работы с коллекцией элементов модели и значения какого типа она должна хранить? PersonModel? PersonViewModel?

Если есть толковый мануал по MVVM - буду рад ссылке.

Comment: Не model view, а view model.

Comment: исправил, спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я всегда придерживаюсь такого подхода:

1) Для CRUD операций использовать репозитории которые инжектить через конструктор. Дабы не смешивать всю логику в одну кучу.

2) ViewModel для коллекции элементов и для одного элемента это разные вещи. Т.е. если делать ViewModel для коллекции то ViewModel будет содержать в себе коллекцию элементов PersonModel.

Пример (Использую MVVMLight):
Для одиночной модели:

```
public interface IItemViewModel<T> where T : ObservableObject
{
    T CurrentItem { get; set; }
}

public class BaseItemViewModel<T> : ViewModelBase, IItemViewModel<T> where T : ObservableObject
{
    protected IRepository<T> Repository;
    private T _currentItem;

    public BaseItemViewModel(IRepository<T> repository)
    {
        Repository = repository;
    }

    public virtual T CurrentItem
    {
        get { return _currentItem; }
        set
        {
            _currentItem = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => CurrentItem);
        }
    }
 }
```

Для коллекции моделей:

```
public interface IItemsViewModel<T> where T : ObservableObject
{
        T CurrentItem { get; set; }

        ObservableCollection<T> Items { get; set; }
}


public class BaseItemsViewModel<T> : ViewModelBase, IItemsViewModel<T> where T : ObservableObject
{
    protected IRepository<T> Repository;
    private T _currentItem;

    public BaseItemsViewModel(IRepository<T> repository)
    {
        Repository = repository;
    }

    public virtual T CurrentItem
    {
        get { return _currentItem; }
        set
        {
            _currentItem = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => CurrentItem);
         }
     }

    public virtual ObservableCollection<T> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: не могли бы Вы показать реализацию конкретной ItemsViewModel? Не могу сообразить как реализован обмен между репозиторием и ObservableCollection. В моем случае нужно тянуть данные из текстового файла.